# Calculating the sum of all prime numbers under 2 million

Tags: python, algorithm

It is giving very big vales when I tested it for 2,20 range and taking a lot of time for 2 million.
What can be wrong?

```py
i=2
sum=0
for a in range(2,2000001):
     for i in range (2,a):
        if a%i==0:   
            break
        else:
            sum=sum+a
print (sum)
```

Comment: That's about the slowest way of finding prime numbers that you could have used.  Find a better algorithm, like the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: @MarkRansom, it's not just slow, it's wrong. if he wanted to sum all prime numbers, the sum should be in another condition outside the inner for.

Comment: Hi Muhammad, welcome! StackOverflow is not meant for this type of question, where you need help getting to grips with programming - maybe look for a discussion board for that.

Comment: @YasinYousif good point, but I read the question as being about slowness not correctness.

Comment: This is the exact probem of Project Euler #10. As others wrote, read a bit about algorithms to produce primes. You wouldn't have written this code if you had.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SymPy to get the prime numbers using Sieve of Eratosthenes, then `sum()` to add them.

To pip install SymPy, use the `pip` command in your terminal:

```
pip install sympy
```

Visit their [installation page](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/install.html) to see other methods of installing.

The [SymPy documentation for prime number related functions](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html) explains how to use their assortment of functions.

This simple code will accomplish what you want:

```py
from sympy import sieve
sieve.extend(2000000)
print(sum(sieve._list))
```

And will print:

```
142913828922
```

Comment: (Note that this code ran in a few seconds on my computer, so if it's taking a while then you might have forgotten `._list`, in which the code is summing all primes to infinity.)

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed that prime numbers fell under the scope of `SymPy`.  Although using it does feel like cheating.

Comment: If you want you could look at the math behind it and try to reproduce it in Python, but even so SymPy would be very useful in calculating that.